# Is there a way to display non printing characters in Windows 10 Wordpad?

Tags: windows-10, wordpad

How can I display non printing characters (new line, space, tab, etc) in Wordpad?

Google search for this is very difficult as all search results seem to be poisoned by instructions about ms word.

How do I do this in wordpad, or is this not supported at all?

Comment: Not supported - use a better text editor such as Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Open Word Pad and check the left hand side and particularly under Print.

(a) There are very limited options (only what is shown). You can also look in the Ribbon at available options.  Very limited.

(b) Displaying non-print characters is not a native Word Pad option.

Open the file in Word to do what you wish.

You do not need to save the Word File (but you can).